# Maven plugin with Java 17

Tags: java, maven, assembly

I want to develop a maven plugin with Java 17. Therefore I have created a maven module using the archetype:

```bash
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.github.siom79.jasyncapicmp -DartifactId=jasyncapicmp-maven-plugin -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin
```

The maven version was updated to 3.9.2.
I have also included a dependency to a library build with Java 17.

When I run `mvn clean install -X` I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:184)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:152)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.analyzeClassStream (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scanArchive (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan (DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.scanAnnotations (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute (JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor (DefaultMojoScanner.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute (AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.HelpGeneratorMojo.execute (HelpGeneratorMojo.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
[...]
```

Looks like the asm `ClassReader` cannot parse class files compiled with Java 17.
Forcing the asm library to a new version via `dependencyManagement` didn't succeed.

Anyone an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show the pom file of the plugin?

Comment: This is the pom.xml: https://github.com/siom79/jasyncapicmp/blob/main/jasyncapicmp-maven-plugin/pom.xml

Comment: The first things I see you have not defined all plugin version in your parent.. (for example surefire plugin, you are not using the most recent versions of plugins( and even worse you have defined different plugin versions in your modules etc... also I can not reproduce the issue...Can you please show how you started your build? Have you run your build from inside your IDE or on plain command line? Also post the full output while getting the error unfortunately I can not recognize where exactly the failure has happened?

Comment: You can reproduce it by: git clone https://github.com/siom79/jasyncapicmp.git, cd jasyncapicmp, edit pom.xml and change the properties maven.compiler.* from 11 to 17 and run mvn clean package.

Comment: Upgrade maven-plugin-plugin and maven-plugin-annotations to most recent version....(3.9.0)... what will fix. Use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>`. instead of source/target...

Comment: After updating to 3.9.0 and maven.compiler.release I get the same issue: Unsupported class file major version 61